# Buttons stop working when I add new div element

Tags: html, button, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I am using sveltekit, typscript, and tailwind for this. Ok, I have a website that I am making and I have buttons that have no background and are formated like this:
When opened

- Label

stuff

when closed

+ Label

It worked and all but when I added a new div to be right next to those buttons the buttons stopped working completely. It would not even show the pointer hand.
Code for buttons:

```
<script lang="ts">
let expanded: boolean = true;
export let item: string = '';
export let value: string[] = [];
import Page from '../Components/page.svelte';
let pagen: string = 'About';
</script>

<Page bind:page={pagen} run="" />
<div class="dropdown flex flex-col mt-5">
<button
    class="dropdown-toggle"
    on:click={() => {
        expanded = !expanded;
    }}
>
    <span class="dropdown-label text-gray-400 ml-5 flex text-lg"
        >{expanded ? `- ${item}` : `+ ${item}`}</span
    >
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content flex" style:display={expanded ? 'block' : 'none'}>
    {#each value as val}
        <div class="dropdown-item text-gray-400 ml-10">
            <p class="inline-block text-gray-400">#</p>
            <button
                on:click={() => {
                    pagen = `{val}`;
                }}>{val}</button
            >
        </div>
    {/each}
    </div>
</div>
```

The pagen that is binded is for the div that goes right next to it. (this is not important I think...)
Code for the page:

```
<script lang="ts">
export let page: string = 'About';
export let run: string = '';
</script>

{#if run == 'true'}
<div class="w-screen h-screen -z-10">
    <div class="page ml-80 bg-gray-800 h-screen">
        {#if page == 'About'}
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                <h1 class="text-gray-400 text-3xl font-bold tracking-wider mt- 
10">Some Title</h1>
                <p class="text-gray-400 text-2xl font-bold tracking-wider">Some 
 Label</p>
            </div>
        {/if}
    </div>
</div>
{/if}
```

These are both components in svelte and are imported in index.svelte. Buttons on top and page on bottom.
Helpful Images:
[image: Website screenshot]

The website is being styled to look like discord.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does `dropdown` classes has any CSS? My guess, your div overlapping button

Comment: the classes you see on the dropdowns is the only css connected to it. How would I fix that?

Comment: You should be able to use browser dev tools to find out if an element is in the way. Chrome's and Firefox's have a button in the top left corner for selecting an element on the page, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I'm noticing that may help you get this working:

Nothing may be showing because `values` may be empty. When I added `values = [ "a", "b", "c" ]` I saw them no problem (see [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/5d32535af00e46a9945793daba5f7981?version=3.49.0)).

You're not setting `run`, so `Page` will never render. Also, using `run` as a string is weird since it appears it is a boolean?

If you're using Tailwind, instead use conditional classes:

```html
<div class="dropdown-content flex" style:display={expanded ? 'block' : 'none'}>

<!-- should be: -->

<div class="dropdown-content flex" style:block={expanded}  style:hidden={!expanded}>
```

Stylistic recommendation:

```html
<span class="dropdown-label text-gray-400 ml-5 flex text-lg">
  {expanded ? `- ${item}` : `+ ${item}`}
</span>

<!-- simpler: -->

<span class="dropdown-label text-gray-400 ml-5 flex text-lg">
  {expanded ? "-" : "+"} {item}
</span>
```

[Here is a repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/5d32535af00e46a9945793daba5f7981?version=3.49.0) with what I believe is working code.

Comment: i laso fixed it by putting "fixed" at the beginning of the class just now